# How to pass two-dimensional array by value to function

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to pass a 2d array to a function. But when I loop through the array in `setParams` there are some extra values in the array (happens for every `case` in the `switch`), I don't know where they are coming from.

```
function setParams(button, params) {


        $mydialog = $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            buttons: {
                "ok": function() {
                     $(this).dialog("close");
                     for(var key in params) {
                        var value = params[key].toString();

                        var arr = value.split(',');
                        alert(arr[0] + "        " + arr[1]);

                        var control = $("#dialog").find('input[name='+arr[1]+']');

                        if (control.is(':checkbox'))
                        {
                            button.data('id')[arr[0]] = control.is(":checked");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            button.data('id')[arr[0]] = control.val();
                        }
                     }
                     sendRequest(button);
                 },
                "cancel": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                 }
             }
        });
    }
```

Menu function

```
$(function() {
        $('#navigationMenu a').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            var button = $(this);
            var cl = button.attr("class");
            console.log(button.attr('href'));

            switch(cl) {
                case "input-params":
                    $('.id').show();
                    $('.requestDate').hide();
                    $('.startEndDate').hide();
                    setParams(button, [["id","id"]]);   
                    break;
                case "input-params-location":
                    $('.id').show();
                    $('.requestDate').hide();
                    $('.startEndDate').hide();
                    setParams(button, [["locationId","id"]]);   
                    break;
                case "input-params-openinghours":
                    $('.id').show();
                    $('.requestDate').show();
                    $('.startEndDate').hide();
                    var myArray = [["locationId","id"],["requestDate","date"]];
                    setParams(button, myArray);
                    break;
               case "input-params-allocations":
                    $('.id').hide();
                    $('.requestDate').hide();
                    $('.startEndDate').show();
                    setParams(button, [["startDate","startDate"],["endDate","endDate"],["includeGroupActivities","includeGroupActivities"]]);
                    break;
               case "input-params-allocations-id":
                    $('.id').show();
                    $('.requestDate').hide();
                    $('.startEndDate').show();
                    setParams(button, [["id","id"],["startDate","startDate"],["endDate","endDate"],["includeGroupActivities","includeGroupActivities"]]);
                    break;
               default:
                    sendRequest(button)
            }

        });
    });
```

Except the values I pass these values are in the array too

1)

```
function (){return v;
}   undefined
```

2)

```
function Array() {[native code]}   undefined
```

3)

```
function (i  v)Array.forEach(this
```

How can I pass the array in a correct way without getting the extra values?

Comment: Since its a 2D array, you should be able to get the values like this `params[0][0]`. this will get the first value of the first element. so when you got this `[["hey", "test], ["hey1", "test1"]` with `params[0][0]` you would get the value `"hey"`.

Answer (score 0):

From your code it's not clear what you mean with 2d array, because to me it only looks like an array with string values.

The extra values you get is functions on the array-object. When you do a for-in loop you loop over the objects properties. In the case of an array this is both the content of the array (properties "0", "1", etc) and native functions. If you want to loop over the content of the array you should use the regular for-loop, or the forEach function that exist on the array.

If you promptly want to use the for-in loop you can check if the property is from the prototype or exist on the instance with `hasOwnProperty`-function.

```
for(var key in params) {
  if(!params.hasOwnProperty(key){
    return;
  }

//rest of the code
}
```